# Only select type int in a column?

Tags: sql, postgresql, types, int, aggregate-functions

I'm looking to select only the columns that I can average. (`Int` is the only I'm aware of, but if there are others, I would like to know.

```
select avg(case when <column> = int then <column> else 0 end)
```

This is what I would try, but it doesn't seem to work. When I try this:

```
Select Avg(<column>) as <alias>
```

It says:

```
ERROR: function avg(double precision) does not exist
```

I'm thinking I may need to add this to the from clause in a join statement, but I'm not exactly certain on how to do that.

Comment: What's `Ave` supposed to be? The Postgres aggregate function for average is [`avg`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-aggregate.html)

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter That might be it. I checked eclipse and it had aggregations as ave, so I figured it was the same for the queries. I'll edit it and leave the question up for people who need help with similar problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Postgres aggregate function for average is **`avg`()** and works for a range of numeric types ***including*** `double precision`. In particular, [per documentation:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-aggregate.html)

> smallint, int, bigint, real, double precision, numeric, or interval

You can use [**`pg_typeof()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-CATALOG-TABLE) to determine the actual data type of any value (or column).

#### Identify columns

To ... `select only the columns that I can average`:

```
SELECT attname, atttypid::regtype::text
FROM   pg_attribute
WHERE  attrelid = 'tbl'::regclass
AND    atttypid = ANY ('{int2,int,int8,real,float8,numeric,interval}'::regtype[])
AND    attnum > 0
AND    NOT attisdropped
ORDER  BY attnum;
```

#### Dynamic computation

It's not a trivial task to dynamically determine the type of a column have the aggregation depend on it.
This would work (excluding the special case `interval`):

```
SELECT avg(CASE WHEN pg_typeof(t_int) = ANY ('{int2,int,int8,real,float8,numeric}'::regtype[])
           THEN t_int::numeric ELSE NULL::numeric END) AS avg_t_int
      ,avg(CASE WHEN pg_typeof(t_num) = ANY ('{int2,int,int8,real,float8,numeric}'::regtype[])
           THEN t_num::numeric ELSE NULL::numeric END) AS avg_t_num
      ,avg(CASE WHEN pg_typeof(t_txt) = ANY ('{int2,int,int8,real,float8,numeric}'::regtype[])
           THEN t_txt::numeric ELSE NULL::numeric END) AS avg_t_txt
FROM tbl;
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5c452/4) demonstrating both.

For big tables it will be more efficient, to check the column type before you assemble your statement dynamically ...

Answer (score 1):

Expression

```
regexp_replace(val, '\d', '', 'g')
```

gives empty string if `val` contains only digits, so

```
select case regexp_replace(val, '\d', '', 'g') 
    when '' then val::int 
    else null end
```

gives integer value if `val` represents unsigned integer, null otherwise.